# Unable to filter messages by recipient in Microsoft Graph Api. One or more invalid nodes

Tags: odata, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get a list of messages that are filtered by recipient from Microsoft Graph API. The url I am using for the request is:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages?$filter=toRecipients/any(r: r/emailAddress/address eq '[Email Address]')`

But I am getting this is the response:

```
{
   "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidUrlQueryFilter",
        "message": "The query filter contains one or more invalid nodes.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "7db712c3-e337-49d9-aa8d-4a5d350d8480",
            "date": "2016-09-28T16:58:34"
        }
    }
}
```

A successful request should look like this (with a lot more data that I have omitted).

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999')/messages",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages?$skip=10",
    "value": [
        {
            "toRecipients": [
                {
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "name": "[Name]",
                        "address": "[Email Address]"
                    }
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

The request works if I remove the filter, and I am able to perform requests with simpler filters.

Is there a problem with my URL, or is there another way to make the request?

Comment: There is definitely something wrong with your $filter parameter.  What exactly are you trying to get with your filter?

Comment: I am trying to get a list of all messages that were sent to a specific email address.

Comment: This definitely looks like a bug, I just spend half day before deciding to go with search. Should've checked here first :(. Exists in Outlook Rest api v1.0 and v2.0 as well. I couldn't find a place to log it though. Anybody knows how to log it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After several hours looking for the solution, I found in the office365 documentation that the property `toRecipients` is not filterable:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#MessageResource

I guess that it's the same in the graph api. So the only solution is using search.

Comment: I can't seem to find a reference for what is filterable. Your link doesn't seem to explain what is and what is not. Neither does it explain it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0 Do you know where I can find an updated list of filterable properties?

Comment: "not filterable" =  (I wasted a bunch of hours on this trying to bend the Graph API to my will!)

Answer (score 10):

Another way to make the request might be to not use filter and use search instead, depending on exactly what you want (and you may have already tried this):

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages?$search="to:[Email Address]"`

Comment: Documentation: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#search-parameter