# Microsoft Graph API: Filter Calendar Events by Attendees

Tags: api, odata, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

Have to filter events by multiple attendees, I don't know the proper way of filtering it.

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=attendees/any(emailadress:startswith(emailadress/name,'xxxxv@xxx.com'))

```
"location": {
            "displayName": "Test"
        },
        "recurrence": null,
        "attendees": [
            {
                "type": "required",
                "status": {
                    "response": "none",
                    "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                },
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "yyyy ",
                    "address": "yyy@yyy.com"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "required",
                "status": {
                    "response": "none",
                    "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                },
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "xxxx",
                    "address": "xxx@xxx.com"
                }
            },
```

I want to get events list where attendess emailaddress are 'xxx@xx.com,yyy@yy.com'

Comment: tried `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=attendees/any(x: x/emailAddress/address eq 'my string')` . but getting error `"'i => i.Attendees.Any(a => (a.EmailAddress == \"my string\"))' is not a supported filter expression."`

Answer (score 2):

From what I'm seeing, event attendee filtering seems to be broken. Check the link below:

[Unable to filter messages...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753969/unable-to-filter-messages-by-recipient-in-microsoft-graph-api-one-or-more-inval)

I'm still searching to see if there's a way, and will update if/when I find something.

It seems like there is an open ticket dealing with this very issue. I've added my information to the ticket, but you might want to, as well.

[Ms Graph Github Issues](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/1771)