# Use search Microsoft Graph API C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to filter the ToReceipient using Graph API in C#.

as per [Unable to filter messages by recipient in Microsoft Graph Api. One or more invalid nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753969/unable-to-filter-messages-by-recipient-in-microsoft-graph-api-one-or-more-inval)

at the moment Filter does not support ToRecipient. I need to use Search.

However in c# as per screenshot and code below, it does not seem to have search property, only filter. Anyone knows how to use Search in Graph API c#? I also need to filter it based on multiple toRecipient Email addresses. Thanks.

```
IUserMessagesCollectionPage msgs = await client.Users["user@domain.com"].Messages.Request().Filter ==> exist

IUserMessagesCollectionPage msgs = await client.Users["user@domain.com"].Messages.Request().Search ==> does not exist
```

[image]

Comment: You can try using QueryOptions class as below `List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
{
     new QueryOption("$search", "lunch")
};
var messages = await client.Users["user@domain.com"].Messages.Request(options).GetAsync();`

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: no it does not work. have you tried the code? do you have a complete sample of the working code? thx

Comment: if I only search gmail it works but if I put the full email address, it does not work saying "." is not a valid charater. What would you do if you have "." in the email address? Thx

Comment: i put another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64528984/queryoption-search-in-graph-api-for-email-address

Comment: I have commented in that thread, please let me know if that helped you.

Comment: Moving this to Answer :)-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using QueryOptions class as below.

```
List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption> 
{            
    new QueryOption("$search", "lunch") 
}; 

var messages = await client.Users["user@domain.com"].Messages.Request(options).GetAsync();
```

You can also use filter, top and other query parameters as well.

Comment: please refer to this link for a more complete answer. Need to put "to:" in the search string param. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64528984/queryoption-search-in-graph-api-for-email-address?noredirect=1#comment114139969_64528984