# QueryOption Search in Graph API for email address

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to search in my sent folder for every email that is sent to "john.smith1@gmail.com"

I tried the following

```
 List<QueryOption> queryOptions = new List<QueryOption> { new QueryOption("$search", "john.smith1@gmail.com") }; 

List<QueryOption> queryOptions = new List<QueryOption> { new QueryOption("$search", "john.smith1%40gmail.com") }; 

 List<QueryOption> queryOptions = new List<QueryOption> { new QueryOption("$search", "to:john.smith1@gmail.com") }; 

List<QueryOption> queryOptions = new List<QueryOption> { new QueryOption("$search", "to:john.smith1%40gmail.com") }; 

  var messages = await client.Users["myuser@mydomain.com"].Messages.Request(queryOptions ).GetAsync();
```

none of the above works. It complains of any non alpha character ( it seems it does not accept number, dot, ":" )

Any advices? Thanks.

Comment: Use it this way - `List<QueryOption> queryOptions = new List<QueryOption> 
                                            { 
                                                new QueryOption("$search", "%22abcd02%40gmail.com%22") 
                                            };`
%22 is nothing but the double quotes. This worked for me.

Comment: hi shiva its working. thanks heaps. You just need to put "to:" , as in List<QueryOption> queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>                                              {                                                  new QueryOption("$search", "%t22to:abcd02%40gmail.com%22")

Can you please put this answer in the thread? I will mark it as the answer and upvote it. If you can't, please let me know and I will put it myself

Comment: do you mind to answer this one as well? Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64544194/search-all-bcc-email-microsoft-graph-api

Comment: Glad to here that it resolves your issue and really happy that you created two SO questions for two different issues. :)-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it this way -

```
List<QueryOption> queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>
{                                                  
    new QueryOption("$search", "%22abcd02%40gmail.com%22") 
};
```

%22 is nothing but the double quotes. We are just concatenating it to work.