# Filter group members by displayName does not work

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, graphserviceclient

I need to provide an endpoint which allows users to search for members within a group

the below code works fine when no filter is passed in (it returns members of the group), but when passing in a `queryString` I get this error

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
> Message: The specified filter to the reference property query is currently not supported.

Is there any sensible way around this?

MS claim that this property is filterable, but is that only through the url API? Does that mean that what I'm trying to do is not possible?

It seems that in their examples they always set `ConsistencyLevel: Eventual` - but I don't see how we can set that using `GraphServiceClient`

I tried adding it as a header:

```
var consistencyLevelHeader = new HeaderOption("consistencylevel", "eventual");
request.Headers.Add(consistencyLevelHeader);
```

but I get the same results

```
var groupId = "guid-of-the-group";

var request = _graphServiceClient.Value.Groups[groupId]
    .Members
    .Request();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString))
{
    request = request.Filter($"startswith(displayName,'{queryString}')");
}

var groupMembersCollection = await request
    .GetAsync();

var userDtos = groupMembersCollection.Select(member =>
    new AzureADAccountDTO
    {
        ProviderKey = member.Id,
        EmailAddress = ((User)member).Mail,
        Name = ((User)member).DisplayName,
    })
    .ToList();

return userDtos;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add $count query parameter as well with `ConsistencyLevel` header to get the successful response.

The request would be something like below

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/0023c709-3556-4296-a6ab-6df2a0a1113c/members?$count=true&$filter=startswith(displayName, 's')`

You can test these graph calls in [Graph Explore](https://aka.ms/ge).

Comment: but how do I add query params when using the SDK as in my question? `Filter` is easy as it provides a method for that

Comment: @Bassie Use queryOptions like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64475666/use-search-microsoft-graph-api-c-sharp/64550884#64550884

Comment: Replace search with count and lunch to true.

Comment: I have tried but getting following response. Unrecognized query argument specified: 'count'.

Comment: This applies to the TypeScript SDK too. BingGPT sent me!