# Microsoft Graph SDK Message Fiter Not Getting Correct Result

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to fetch `toRecipients` from `me/messages`. I am getting correct result.
Here is the results.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('a803fa7d-d3b5-4065-882c-e9df1ca6a093')/messages(toRecipients)",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?o=json&$select=toRecipients&$skip=10",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAAB6+NCu/3QGSbvxDC/F5lT6AAAaysW0\"",
            "id": "AAMkADZjNjAxZjY2LWNiNDQtNDQyMS05Y2Y3LTY3YTM5",
            "toRecipients": [
                {
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "name": "MyAnalytics",
                        "address": "no-reply@microsoft.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAAB6+NCu/3QGSbvxDC/F5lT6AAAaytNp\"",
            "id": "AAMkADZjNjAxZjY2LWNiNDQtNDQyMS05",
            "toRecipients": [
                {
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "name": "Test Email",
                        "address": "test@email.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAAB6+NCu/3QGSbvxDC/F5lT6AAAaysWw\"",
            "id": "AAMkADZjNjAxZ-FAAA=",
            "toRecipients": [
                {
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "name": "MyAnalytics",
                        "address": "no-reply@microsoft.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I am trying to `filter` with condition, result it's not working. What I am trying to filter is "MyAnalytics". I want to set condition where `toRecipients` `emailAddress` `name` not equal to `MyAnalytics` Here is my code

```cs
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            SecureString pass = new NetworkCredential("", "myPass").SecurePassword;
            var messages = graphClient.Me.Messages.Request()
                  .Select(mail => new
                  {
                      mail.ToRecipients
                  })
            .Top(3)
            .Filter($"ToRecipients.emailAddress.name ne 'MyAnalytics'")
            .WithUsernamePassword("myEmail", pass).GetAsync().Result;
```

**`Note:`** Basically I want top 3 `toRecipients` where `emailAddress` `name` not equal to `MyAnalytics` or `address` not equal to 'no-reply@microsoft.com'

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally we should use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=toRecipients/any(c:c/emailAddress/name ne 'MyAnalytics')`.

But in fact the property `toRecipients` is not filterable based on my test. A similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753969/unable-to-filter-messages-by-recipient-in-microsoft-graph-api-one-or-more-inval?answertab=votes#tab-top) for your reference.

As you want to exclude the emails, using `search` is not an option.

I'm afraid that we have to get the results first and exclude those emails by checking `emailAddress/name` in our own code logic.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I also tried that but seems  filters doesn't work. I tryied to get top 3 email then filter with linq query finally binded into list. No other ways at this moment.