# How do you query a list of message id's on MS Graph? Current response says invalid nodes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, odata

My query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages?$filter=id+in+('AAMkAGVmMDEzMTM4LTZmYWUtNDdkNC1hMDZiLTU1OGY5OTZhYmY4OABGAAAAAAAiQ8W967B7TKBjgx9rVEURBwAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAAAAAEMAAAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAUEQPKcAAA=','AAMkAGVmMDEzMTM4LTZmYWUtNDdkNC1hMDZiLTU1OGY5OTZhYmY4OABGAAAAAAAiQ8W967B7TKBjgx9rVEURBwAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAAAAAEMAAAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAT57zAUAAA=')
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidUrlQueryFilter",
        "message": "The query filter contains one or more invalid nodes."
    }
}
```

If this is not the way to do it. How do you do it?

This answer to a similar question seems to indicate that some properties are just not filterable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44965572/5078765

Perhaps is the id field not filterable in such a way?

*Addendum:*

I've also tried the `search.in()` method described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-filter#code-try-17

Like so:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=search.in(id,'AAMkAGVmMDEzMTM4LTZmYWUtNDdkNC1hMDZiLTU1OGY5OTZhYmY4OABGAAAAAAAiQ8W967B7TKBjgx9rVEURBwAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAAAAAEMAAAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAUEQPKcAAA=,AAMkAGVmMDEzMTM4LTZmYWUtNDdkNC1hMDZiLTU1OGY5OTZhYmY4OABGAAAAAAAiQ8W967B7TKBjgx9rVEURBwAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAAAAAEMAAAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAT57zAUAAA=',',')
```

But this returns a different error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-01-12T21:34:46",
            "request-id": "993206ca-950d-4f0f-aee1-149219509b04",
            "client-request-id": "993206ca-950d-4f0f-aee1-149219509b04"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the ids passed in the filter parameter are in the correct format and you are using the correct version of the API.

Check the permissions you have on your access token, maybe you don't have the permission to use this filter.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have permission, there is no permission error. I tried using my own credentials with the Postman application and then I tried using the Graph Explorer using the demo credentials but they both give similar errors. If I make a very similar request but instead query "groups" it seems to work fine and I can get the groups I want.

Comment: If you can provide a query string that works on the Graph Explorer that fetches 2 or more specific emails by their ID, you have found a solution to my problem. Graph Explorer here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to call `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/{id}` endpoint?

Comment: If you try filter id with `eq`: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=id eq '{message_id}'` it will return error message `The property 'Id' does not support filtering.`

Comment: @user2250152 That's sad. I just want to be able to pull a collection of them instead of just one single item.

Comment: Do you might know the answer to this one as well?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75245865/copybatchrequestproperties-and-deleterequestcontainer-replacement-in-aspnetcore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Id of the entity, as Glen Scales correctly noted. If you try to query using filter to the only one id you'll see self-explanatory message

```
GET 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?filter=id eq 'AAMkA..8AAA='

{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidProperty",
        "message": "The property 'id' does not support filtering."
    }
}
```

Also, in MSGraph `filter` operators allowed depend on resource and field type. I.e. for [GUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter?tabs=http#for-guid-types) types only `eq` and `not` operators are supported in `filter`.

Check if [extended properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extended-properties-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) may serve your needs: first you mark a set of messages with a single value extended property, for example, and later you can filter messages by that property

Comment: Thank you, but before I accept your answer, what is a GUID type and how am I supposed to know that a "message resource type" is also a GUID type? The message resource page does not mention the word GUID anywhere.

Comment: message id is not definitely GUID.

Comment: @user2250152 yes, you're right. But MS documentation is not always perfect, unfortunately, so I thought it's the case of wording. 
ADJenks, GUID is a global unique identifier. As soon as get to pc, I've checked, and really you cannot filter by id as mentioned in Glen's answer (regardless of identifier's type). But I couldn't find this mentioned anywhere in documentation. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ah, yes, I know what a GUID is but I didn't understand what make a particular object a GUID type, I guess it's a GUID type if its primary identifier is a GUID? This is why I was confused, because the message ID was not a GUID so I thought something else must make it a GUID type.

Comment: It's silly that the error message is much more clear when you're only filtering on one...

Comment: Do you might know the answer to this one as well?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75245865/copybatchrequestproperties-and-deleterequestcontainer-replacement-in-aspnetcore

Answer (score 1):

You can't query by the Id property if you want to know if a message exists then you need to bind/get the item in question. Eg a batch get on the Id's you have and check for the batch response to see which one's exist (or not) you have the identifiers already so a search isn't needed and is much more expensive. If you want a message Identifier you can query on use the either the InternetMessageId or the PidTagSearchKey https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagsearchkey-canonical-property the latter should be unique.

Comment: Why can't I query by the Id property and where does it specify this?
Also, I see that there is an InternetMessageId, but I don't see PidTagSearchKey as a property of a MS Graph message resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Also, I'm sorry but your answer seems to be missing commas or something, so it's a bit difficult for me to read. Also I don't know what "bind" means in relation to Microsoft's Graph API.

Comment: This also seems to fail: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=internetMessageId in ('<SJ0PR15MB52454C1CDA1124CEFE6DBBBBCD0A9@SJ0PR15MB5245.namprd15.prod.outlook.com>')`

Comment: I'm pretty sure In isn't supported in the Mail endpoint so you need to use an OR filter if you wish to do it. A filter is really the wrong way to go about this from a performance point of view, the mail API's are optimized to bind to multiple items at once (as they is the way a lot of email client work) doing large filters on folders with large item count is not the best way to go.

Comment: Yes, it seems it's not supported, and @kadis showed good proof of that. Sorry, once again, I don't know what "bind" means in this context and I can't seem to find a reference to the word bind in any of the mail or graph documentation. From my perspective, a filter directly on a list of primary keys seems like something that should be very performant. It all depends on how it's implemented. I'm not sure how it all works under the hood, but from an API user perspective with no knowledge of the internal workings, this should be simple, but you seem to have a deeper understanding of MS Exchange.

Comment: A bind it just a Get on a particular GraphId (in EWS it was method in the Managed API that did the GetItem operation). Exchange isn't a RDBMS its more inline with NOSQL but predates most of these. An Id will contain all the routing information the backend needs to know to get to an Item, that item maybe in the users mailbox or any mailbox so its a global indentifier in this regard and one of reasons its not filterable.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes a lot of sense now. Thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: Do you might know the answer to this one as well?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75245865/copybatchrequestproperties-and-deleterequestcontainer-replacement-in-aspnetcore